# Unwanted UITableViewCellAccessory magically appears after segue (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, segue

I have an app which shows which colleagues are inside the office and which aren't (based on awesome iBeacon stuff). However, the UITableView that displays them isn't working as expected.

It's hard to explain so I added some pictures.

Below is how the tableView normally looks.

[image: Normal state of the tableView]

These are custom cells with an UIImage and a UILabel. I also gave every cell an action on the right side which starts a segue to his/her profile page.

[image: Action on the right]

When pressing this button, the segue starts and I can revert back (navigation controller) to this ViewController. Everything still works fine here.

On top you also have the UISearchBar to search for a specific person. This additional tableView works as expected and the person found also gets an action with a segue to his/her profile page.

[image: Action on SearchResultTableView]

However, when I return to the tableView after THIS segue (only this one, the one from the normal tableView works fine), there are suddenly unwanted accessory icons added to my cells.

[image: Unwanted accessory icons]

What gives? Did I do something wrong? The action field has the following code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var pingAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Ping", handler:{action, indexpath in
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        self.searchDisplayController?.setActive(false, animated: false)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openMap", sender: indexPath)
    })
    pingAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 232/255, green: 75/255, blue: 4/255, alpha: 1)

    return [pingAction]
}
```

Without this line

```
self.searchDisplayController?.setActive(false, animated: false)
```

Upon returning to this screen, the ViewController would even be completely black.

I never gave my cells any accessoryView in my code and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I even wrote

```
customCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
```

But no luck. The weird thing is that it uses pretty much the exact same segue when going to the profile page from the normal tableView and from the searchResultsTableView, however this last one gives troubles when doing so.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ... // Other segues
    else if segue.identifier == "openMap" {
        let dvc: MapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MapViewController
        var person: Person

        if self.searchDisplayController!.active == true {
            tableView = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView
            person = self.filteredPersons[sender!.row]
        } else {
            tableView = self.tblPersons as UITableView
            person = personsManager.getPersonsMixed()[sender!.section][sender!.row]
        }

        dvc.person = person
    }
    ... // Other segues
```

Any help would be nice to get, I've been stuck on this problem for quite a bit hours now already. Sorry for the long question with lot's of images and code snippets, but I have no idea where the problem is situated so I try to give as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by dropping the entire UISearchDisplayController and implementing a UISearchController instead.

Turns out the UISearchDisplayController was showing as deprecated in the latest Xcode beta build anyway.